# Can a Java application connect directly to EnterpriseDB Advanced Server?

Tags: java, postgresql, enterprisedb, database-connectivity

Team,
I have a Java application that I want to access EnterpriseDB (EDB) Advanced Server.  For example:
**myJavaApp => EDB Advanced Server v11**
or does the connection look like this
**myJavaApp => Java Driver v42 => EDB Advanced Server v11**
I have a high volume application and I want to make the path length as skinny as possible to achieve required throughput.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: The Java JDBC driver is the glue that converts JDBC calls into whatever the database requires.  You would not want to connect to the underlying database yourself, you'd just be reinventing the wheel (and probably not doing as good a job).  Also, compared to network latency, your code, and the database's execution time, the JDBC cost is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDB produces an `edb-jdbc` driver for users who wish to connect to EDB Postgres Advanced Server databases.  This will be installed via a Yum or Apt repository -- please contact EDB Support or an EDB Account Exec for info!